# Need to root airmong

Tags: software-installation, aircrack-ng, kali-linux-tools

james@DESKTOP:~$ sudo airmon-ng

PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset

james@DESKTOP:~$ airmon-ng
Run it as root

Comment: You've not provided the basic starting point; ie. what Ubuntu product & release.